# if statements where x can equal a series of numbers/a range of numbers?

Tags: java, if-statement, range

Trying to write a program for a combination lock, where if the inputted number is within 3 numbers of the correct number it will state that the lock is open. (i.e if the first number of the lock combination is 5, it will state that the lock is open if someone inputs 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, or 8.)

This is the code I have so far
(I'm only trying to figure out how to get the program to recognize whether or not the first number is correct at the moment, if you're wondering why there is a second + third input.)

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the first number: ");
    int first = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the second number: ");
    int second = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print ("Enter the third number: ");
    int third = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (first == )
        System.out.println("It works!");
    else
        System.out.println("It didn't work");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may check that the difference is within a range of 3,  by using the absolute value of `first - lock` (or `lock - first`, as you prefer) .

```
if(Math.abs(first-lock)<=3)
```

Comment: Can't vote anymore for today, but this sure deserve an upvote x)

Comment: Could you explain this code in words? I'm really new to coding and an explanation of this would be really helpful if I had to use it in the future.

Comment: `Math.abs()` returns the absolute value of the argument you pass to it, then you want first to be in a +3/-3 range of lock, so if the difference between `lock` and `first` is less than 3 you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks @xoxel. Indeed the purpose is to calculate the distance, without having to check the positive distance and the negative distance.The absolute value does just that (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs-int-)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could do it:

```
If (first <= lock + 3 && first >= lock - 3)
    //do something
```

Assuming `Lock` is your "5" as in your example and `first` the input you are willing to check.

Comment: If `first` is 2 or 8, this won't pass the `if` statement.

Comment: Honestly can't see why, could you explain more ? :)

Comment: If `first` is 2, then: `first > lock - 3` => `2 > 5 - 3` => `2 > 2` => `false`.

Comment: Wow ! Thanks, not sure if it usefull since Berger gave a better answer, but i'am gonna edit mine, just in case, `<=`&& `>=` should fix that....